# Determining a password-hashing function knowing plaintext + output

Tags: deobfuscation, hash-functions

I have a password that has been stored and I'd like to figure out how it's been 'transformed' to be stored in my database.

The plaintext password is:

`k4oK203$`

And the password as it is stored 'crypted' in my database is:

`6xqmRr0QNUrc0uvwGchWqA==`

How would I go about figuring out what transformation (base64? sha1? md5? etc.) that were used in order to get the plain text password in to the database value?

Comment: The crypted string does not occur in the output of md5, sha1, sha2, sha3 functions.  Does your database contain a salt for your password?

Comment: It might also be not hashing, but encrypting (zero-padding and applying a symmetric cypher with some unknown key).

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. My first hunch for such a case would be to visit the [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef) (or install it locally) and see if I can make sense of the data with it.

Comment: @0xC0000022L that is really cool, thank you! Is there a way to specify a known output in that tool? It seems you can only enter in the input and it can guess/brute-force the output. How might you go about doing the above on there?